# Open specific app based on URL

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I will like to open an app if the url

for example if the person opens : `http://www.example.com/id=100,` i would like to parse `example.com` and show options to open it with my app.

The same functionality is used by youtube, if you click on youtube link it will either ask if you would like to open it using youtube or directly play youtube video

Comment: Use an intent. The answer by Nirav should work for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a [`data specification`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html) to your intent filter with the http schema and the domain you want to open with your app.

```
<intent-filter ... >
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="example.com" />
    ...
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Umh, that line up there is the snippet from the manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```